# get original dst failed in container

Tags: go, networking, linux-kernel, containers, ipvs

I am designing an http service and need to get the real destination IP. The network on the host looks like this（just like k8s kubeproxy doing）：

```
traffic arrived host -> host ipvs -> docker bridge -> container
```

My service(golang) runs in container, but there is an IPVS load balancer that do dnat in front, so I need to get original dst in some way, I know I can use `syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq` to get real dst, but it just work when service run in host,if run in container,the code failed with err：`syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq: no such file or directory`

container use docker, run in bridge mod, this is my service code：

```golang
package main

import (
   "context"
   "fmt"
   "net"
   "net/http"
   "syscall"
)

const SO_ORIGINAL_DST = 80

type contextKey struct {
   key string
}

var ConnContextKey = &contextKey{"http-conn"}

func SaveConnInContext(ctx context.Context, c net.Conn) context.Context {
   return context.WithValue(ctx, ConnContextKey, c)
}
func GetConn(r *http.Request) net.Conn {
   return r.Context().Value(ConnContextKey).(net.Conn)
}

func getOriginalDst(conn net.Conn) (string, int, error) {
   tc, ok := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
   if !ok {
      return "", 0, fmt.Errorf("redirect proxy only support tcp")
   }

   f, err := tc.File()
   if err != nil {
      return "", 0, fmt.Errorf("get conn file error, err: %s", err)
   }
   defer f.Close()

   addr, err := syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq(int(f.Fd()), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST)
   if err != nil {
      return "", 0, fmt.Errorf("syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq: %s", err)
   }

   p0 := int(addr.Multiaddr[2])
   p1 := int(addr.Multiaddr[3])

   port := p0*256 + p1

   ips := addr.Multiaddr[4:8]
   ip := fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ips[0], ips[1], ips[2], ips[3])

   return ip, port, nil
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   conn := GetConn(req)

   ip, port, err := getOriginalDst(conn)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("get original dst failed: %s", err))
      return
   }
   msg := fmt.Sprintf("source addr: %s, server addr: %s, original dst: %s:%d \n",
      req.RemoteAddr, req.Context().Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey), ip, port)
   fmt.Fprintf(w, msg)
}

func version(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "v4")
}

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", version)
   http.HandleFunc("/test", hello)

   addr := "0.0.0.0:9090"
   srv := http.Server{
      ConnContext: SaveConnInContext,
   }
   //server.ListenAndServe()
   ln, err := net.Listen("tcp4", addr)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   srv.Serve(ln)
}
```

if service run on the host it works ok：

1. `sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9090`
2. `curl localhost:8080/test`
3. get expected answer

```
source addr: 127.0.0.1:21918, server addr: 127.0.0.1:9090, original dst: 127.0.0.1:9090
```

If the service run in container then the request will fail

```
➜  ~ curl 172.17.0.2:9090/test
get original dst failed: syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq: no such file or directory
```

I have tried many ways. At first I thought it was a permission problem. Adding --`privileged=true -u=root` is still useless.

I expect the code can work and get original dst in container.

Comment: Please include text input and output as text, not picture. For many people the pictures may be inaccessible and the text won't be searchable for people getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, fixed it, I replaced it with text